# How to select a row by primary key in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find a way to select a row in sqlite from Python. Say I have a table `soft drinks` with columns `drink` and `price`, with the primary key being `drink name`. I want to select `coke` out of `drink` name. How would I do this without looping through every single entry?

Here's my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.Connection("database.db")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("create table soft drinks (drink name TEXT, drink TEXT, price INTEGER)"
curs.execute("insert into soft drinks (drink name, drink, price) values ("coke", "whatever", 89)")
```

I'm looking for a command something like `curs.execute(select "coke" from soft drinks)` and it will return the whole row.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.  Use the `{}` button to make your code look like code.

Comment: Why do your table and column names have spaces in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses [quotation marks as column identifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), so you'd need to put quotation marks around the column and table name: `SELECT * FROM "soft drinks" WHERE "drink name" = 'Coke';`

Comment: You should use parameter substitution to do this, (http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) `'SELECT * FROM "soft drinks WHERE "drink name" = ?',beverage`

Comment: Missed " after `soft drinks`